# ProcessBatchData error

Tags: 2010, development

I am trying to run a batch process to insert items into a list. I am running into an error "Cannot complete action. Please try again." which I believe means that there is something wrong with my batch xml. This is my first time writing a batch for inserting items. I have a batch that deletes items without issue in the same block of code, so I am fairly certain the issue is with the xml.

```
StringBuilder batchString1 = new StringBuilder();
batchString1.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
batchString1.Append("<ows:Batch OnError=\"Return\">");
string destListID = destList.ID.ToString();
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    batchString1.Append("<Method>");
    batchString1.Append("<SetList Scope=\"Request\">" + Convert.ToString(destListID) + "</SetList>");
    batchString1.Append("<SetVar Name=\"ID\">New</SetVar>");
    batchString1.Append("<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Save</SetVar>");
    batchString1.Append("<SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Title\">Title here</SetVar>");
    batchString1.Append("</Method>");
}
batchString.Append("</ows:Batch>");
web.ProcessBatchData(batchString1.ToString());
```

Items is just an SPListItemCollection from a different list.

Comment: Have you checked the ULS logs for more details about the cause of the error?

Comment: Yes, my understanding was that it pointed to the same thing: 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ProcessBatchData(String bstrUrl, String bstrData, ISPDataCallback pResultCallback) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProcessBatchData(String strBatchData) at CMSync.CMSync.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. I never actually closed the xml. Last append is to a batchString variable instead of a batchString1 variable. I have to be less lazy about my naming.

```
batchString.Append("</ows:Batch>");
```